# How does $(x^{ed} - x) $mod n $= 0$ simplify to $((x^e)^d) $mod $n = x$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I'm trying to follow this proof about RSA

n is the product of two distinct primes. $ e * d$ mod $\phi(n)$ = 1 with $ e,d \in \Bbb{N}$

In the last line how does $(x^{ed} - x) $mod n $= 0$ simplify to $((x^e)^d) $mod $n = x$

from script (also meaning it follows in this context)
[image]

Comment: Do you know Euler's Theorem ?. if yes try to apply it.

Comment: exponents, multiplication, addition, and substraction are preserved over modular arithmetic.  So $x^{ed} - x \equiv 0 \pmod n \implies (x^e)^d \equiv x \pmod n$ for the exact same reasons $x^{ed}-x = 0\implies (x^e)^d = x$.

Comment: Yes but the conclusion is (x^ed -x) mod n = 0 <=> x^ed mod n - x mod n = 0 <=> x^ed mod n = x mod n which is not the same as x^ed mod n  = x...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x^{ed}-x \equiv 0 \pmod n\\
x^{ed} \equiv x \pmod n\\
(x^e)^d \equiv x \pmod n$$
The second line adds $x$ to each side, the third is by a property of exponents.

Comment: In my script it states x^ed mod n = x (without mod n on this side)

Comment: It is using $\bmod n$ as an operation, returning the remainder on division by $n$.  That is a computer science way to write it because they have an operator, often written with the percent sign.  In math we talk of equivalence modulo $n$.  In most cases, including this one, they are equivalent.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't follow the reasoning..(x^ed -x) mod n = 0 <=> x^ed mod n - x mod n = 0 <=> x^ed mod n = x mod n which is not the same as x^ed mod n = x

Comment: I gave the reasons in the answer.  As long as $x \lt n$ they are equivalent.